# Why does git pull cause local changes I did not make

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I am working with two collaborators in a git repository. I recently committed some changes locally, then pulled from our github repo of the work. This caused a couple of conflicts which I resolved. However, along with the pull that caused these minor conflicts, I have now got a bunch of other files marked as changed in my local repository. Inspecting the diffs of the files, I can see that these are changes my collaborators must have made. I assume they must have committed them, as that would be the only way they could have ended up in my local repository. But how can their comitted changes end up appearing in my local repository as if they were changes by me which I now need to commit?
P.S. I may be handicapped from being a long-term Subversion user, quite new to git...

Based on comments below and @wmfairuz' answer, I learned that when I have locally comitted changes to file A, pull a changeset that modifies files A & B, I need to commit both files A & B after resolving changes in A, even though my conflict resolution only modifies file A, right?

Now, the problem is actually a bit more complicated. I had actually committed changes to file A and in addition, I had uncommitted changes to a set of files C. I do not wish to commit the files C - they are mostly LaTeX and Python output files stored in the repo for convenience which were updated due to running Python and LaTeX on their sources, but I do not wish to record these changes. I then pulled a changeset that modified the file A and a set of files B. Due to my git ignorance, I unstaged the automatically staged changes to file set B when committing the resolved file A. Now I can no longer distinguish the sets C & B. What should I do to complete the merge correctly and avoid somehow destroying the file set B?

Comment: `git pull` is really a combination of two commands: `fetch` and `merge`. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: Their changes showed up because you `pull`ed (ie `fetch`ed and `merge`d) the changes.

Comment: Yes, but why do their changes now appear to be uncommitted changes at my end?

Comment: without knowing exactly which commands you use and what happened during the merge, in which order, this is can probably not be diagnosed. it might be leftovers from your conflicts, or it might be other stuff, but that's hard to tell without your history and command log

Comment: My guess is that you are still mid-merge. Merge started, noticed conflicts, and stopped for you to fix them, which you did, but you don't say that you then `git add`ed the fixed files and `git commit`ted the merge. But that's just a guess...

Comment: I fixed conflicts in one file using 'git mergetool' which started Meld, in which I combined changes and saved. Afterwards, I opened git-cola, unstaged a large number of files that "something" seemed to have staged automatically, and staged and committed only the resolved file. Now, the mysterious local changes are in some of the files that something else staged automatically, which I did not edit during this conflict resolution. I found it safer to unstage those apparently automatically staged files since I had not done anything to them.

Comment: That "something else" was probably the rest of the merge that hadn't been committed yet, because `git merge` paused before committing to allow you to fix conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal.

Let say the conflicted file is part of a commit that modifies file A (the conflicted file) and file B.
When a merge is failed, the commit is pending until you fix the conflict and merge it yourself. So it's normal that in your case, file B appears as changed file.

So at each merge conflict, what you need to do is to: fix the conflict, add the conflicted file AND add all changed file from the commit. Then merge. So at the end, you will have a slightly different commit (slightly different file A + the normal changes for file B)

Comment: Oh, I see. Now that I actually committed the resolved file A, what happens to file B that I did not commit? I suppose my collaborators' already checked-in changes to that file are still in the github repo?

Comment: I added further details to the question to clarify the mess I am currently in, which I have no idea how to solve. Sigh - I definitely need to practice my git moves...

Comment: The best way is to make sure your working area is clean before doing the pull. You have several ways of doing this. One way is to use git stash. It will stash your uncommited changes, thus making your working area clean. You can get them later by doing git stash pop.

Comment: To do a merge you can only add the files you want to be in the merge. If it's file A, and B and you don't want file C, Just don't add file C. You can verify the original commit by doing git show <commit-id> on the remote branch. That way, you can see what files to add.